# How to extract list of all brands from amazon using scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to crawl using scrapy on amazon.com  and trying to collect all data listed brands.
Here is scrapy script::

```
class StayuncleCrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'amazon_crawler'

    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_a_V?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=a&ie=UTF8&qid=1466664617']
    CrawlSpider.DOWNLOAD_DELAY=2; 
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("/gp/search/other/ref")), callback='parse_item', follow=True) ]

    def parse_item(self,response):
        global i
        body = response.xpath('//body//div[@id="center"]')
        texts = body.xpath('.//span').extract()
        print texts
        ptext ="/Users/Nand/crawledData/html/"+response.url.split("/")[-2] +str(i)+'.txt'
        for text in texts:
            if text:
                            text = text.rstrip()
                print text.encode('utf-8')
                            with open(ptext, 'ab') as f:
                             f.write(text.encode('utf-8'))
                             f.write("\n") 


    item = DmozItem()
    yield item
```

Here is starting URL

```
 https://www.amazon.com/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_a_V?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=a&ie=UTF8&qid=1466664617
```

Here is HTML part that i want to crawl

```
 <div class="a-row a-spacing-none pagn">
<span class="pagnLead">Viewing:</span>
<span class="pagnLink"><a href="/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_-2_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&amp;pickerToList=brandtextbin&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1466668789">Top Brands</a>
                                    </span>
```

[#](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_1_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=%23&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        A[B](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_b_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=b&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [C](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_c_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=c&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [D](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_d_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=d&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [E](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_e_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=e&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [F](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_f_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=f&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [G](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_g_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=g&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [H](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_h_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=h&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [I](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_i_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=i&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [J](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_j_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=j&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [K](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_k_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=k&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [L](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_l_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=l&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [M](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_m_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=m&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [N](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_n_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=n&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [O](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_o_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=o&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [P](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_p_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=p&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [Q](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_q_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=q&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [R](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_r_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=r&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [S](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_s_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=s&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [T](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_t_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=t&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [U](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_u_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=u&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [V](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_v_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=v&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [W](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_w_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=w&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [X](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_x_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=x&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [Y](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_y_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=y&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)
                                        [Z](/gp/search/other/ref=sr_in_z_A?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A172282&pickerToList=brandtextbin&indexField=z&ie=UTF8&qid=1466668789)

I am trying to follow all link defined using listed alphabets above  under `div id indexBarHeader`  and trying to print all listed brand like

```
A & I Products
A & L Engraving
and so on..
```

Can some one help to correct my script